# How to remove bullets from the gutter toolbar in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I don't know how these bullets appeared in my gutter toolbar:

[image: sublime text screen shot]

How can I remove this from my Sublime editor?

Answer (score 3):

This is done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It can be removed by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Make sure you do both and in order (K first and then G). You can also remove it/add in the edit menu and finding the mark option.

Comment: :( it does not work! When i used the mark feature, but the bullets have black color and does not round the text with a border -> http://i.imgur.com/zmktN.png

Comment: When you remove the mark, does the blue one come back up?

Comment: yes, it doesn't disappear... :(

Comment: Did you install any packages?

Comment: Nope, the last package that i installed was PrettyJSON. I tried removing it, but nothing happens

Comment: Try go to "Goto"->Booksmarks->Clear bookmarks. If that doesn't work, you must have something like SublimeLinter installed.

Comment: nothing :( and i don't have Linter installed :( this is very weird

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, which was to remove the SublimeRope plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it appears that SublimeRope was trying to flag errors using its linting capability.

Without having to uninstall the otherwise useful packages, you can usually just disable the linting feature as is suggested in this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles/25718448#25718448